# Error while stating hadoop namenode in windows for command hadoop namenode -format

Tags: windows, hadoop, installation, hdfs, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I got error while executing this command to start the namenode.

`c:\hadoop-2.3.0\bin>hadoop namenode -format
    DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.

    Instead use the hdfs command for it.

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: V 
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: V
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: V.  Program will exit.`

Comment: A screenshot of a terminal window that doesn't even include the actual query that resulted in the error isn't going to get much attention here.  Instead, edit your question and copy and paste the actual command, and error into the question text.  Then take a few minutes to provide some context about what you're trying to do.